# Best way to pass variables between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am very new to xcode & Objective-C (having come from PHP) i have started to play around and am finding it very hard to pass variables between views this is what i have so far:

**Game_info.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Game_Info : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *groupName;
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *gameType;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *groupName;


- (IBAction) GameTypePicker;
- (IBAction) KeyboardHide;
- (IBAction) BackBTN;
- (IBAction) NextBTN;

@end
```

**Game_Info.m**

```
#import "I_Dare_YouViewController.h"
#import "Game_Info.h"
#import "Game_TDoR.h"


    @implementation Game_Info
    @synthesize groupName;


// Next Button
-(IBAction) NextBTN{
    if ([groupName.text length] == 0) {
        // Alert
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Group Name" 
                              message:@"Please enter a group name" 
                              delegate:self 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil
                              ];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }else if([groupName.text length] < 3){
        // Alert
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Group Name" 
                              message:@"Please enter a name longer than 3 characters" 
                              delegate:self 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil
                              ];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }else{
        Game_TDoR *screen = [[Game_TDoR alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
        [screen release];

        Game_TDoR *screen1 = [[Game_TDoR alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        NSLog(@"Game_Info: %@",self.groupName.text);
        screen1.groupNameText = self.groupName.text; 
        [self presentModalViewController:screen1 animated:YES];
        [screen1 release];

    }
}
```

Then in another view / .h / .m file i am trying to get to the 'groupName' property.

**Game_TDoR.m**

```
#import "I_Dare_YouViewController.h"
#import "Game_Info.h"
#import "Game_TDoR.h"
@implementation Game_TDoR
@synthesize groupNameText,Testlbl;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Game_TDoR: %@",self.groupNameText);
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",[self.groupNameText capitalizedString]];
    [Testlbl setText:msg];
    [msg release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

So what i am trying to do is on the first view page (Game_info) there is an input text box and im trying to pass that to a label on another view page (Game_TDoR)

This is what comes out in the NSLog (note that the second page (Game_TDoR) comes out first in the log.

```
2011-07-17 00:25:34.765 I Dare You[3941:207] Game_TDoR: (null)
2011-07-17 00:25:34.774 I Dare You[3941:207] Game_Info: Name
```

Problem solved:

On the next button i needed to add the variable before i moved page (not the other way around - silly noobish thing to do...)

```
        Game_TDoR *screen1 = [[Game_TDoR alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        NSLog(@"Game_Info: %@",self.groupName.text);
        screen1.groupNameText = self.groupName.text; 
        [self presentModalViewController:screen1 animated:YES];
        [screen1 release];

        Game_TDoR *screen = [[Game_TDoR alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
        [screen release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass the value of `groupName.text` from the `Game_Info` view controller to the `Game_TDoR` view controller, which is presented modally by the former, you can declare a property in `Game_TDoR` to hold the value:

1) Declare a `NSString` property in `Game_TDoR` @interface block:

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *groupNameText;
```

(Remember to synthesize or implement the accessor methods in the implementation block)

2) In `NextBTN` action, after you initialize your `Game_TDoR` instance, set the property:

```
Game_TDoR *screen = [[Game_TDoR alloc] init...];
screen.groupNameText = self.groupName.text;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just have a little problem everything seems to be working fine apart from when trying to view groupNameText in a UILabel it says '(Null)' & when i try to NSLog it to see what comes out it says 'Format not a string literal and no format arguments'

Comment: @Eli.Stone How do you set the label text? Can you post some code? This is how I would log it: `NSLog(@"groupNameText: %@", self.groupNameText);`

Comment: this is what i have done in game info on clicking the button: Game_TDoR *screen1 = [[Game_TDoR alloc] init]; screen1.groupNameText = self.groupName.text;[screen1 release]; then the rest is: @property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *groupNameText;
but this just returns null

Comment: I assume you present `screen1` modally before you release it (`[self presentModalViewController:screen1 animated:YES];`), right? Also, if you log `groupNameText` (`NSLog(@"groupNameText: %@", self.groupNameText);`) in `Game_TDoR`'s `viewDidLoad`, what is the output?

Comment: Well i have now :) So this is the whole code i have to send to next view `Game_TDoR *screen1 = [[Game_TDoR alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; screen1.groupNameText = self.groupName.text;[self presentModalViewController:screen1 animated:YES];[screen1 release];` and to get from another view:`NSLog(@"Logged: %@",self.groupNameText);NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",[self.groupNameText capitalizedString]];[Testlbl setText:msg];[msg release];)` But both the label i have created & NSLog return '(Null)'

Comment: What is the output if you log `self.groupName.text` just before `screen1.groupNameText = self.groupName.text;`?

Comment: @Eli.Stone Also, can you update your question with the current code of `Game_TDoR`'s `viewDidLoad` method? In the original question there is a bug: `if(groupName.text = 0){`. This statement is assigning 0 (`nil`) to groupName.text, which is different from `if(groupName.text == 0){` (note the double `=`)

Comment: Updated question, and the log works fine it gets the information taken from the UITextField. The only thing i noticed was that in the log file the second page NSLog comes up first. `2011-07-16 20:57:24.847 I Dare You[3740:207] SecondPage: (null)
2011-07-16 20:57:24.850 I Dare You[3740:207] FirstPage: Stone`

Comment: @Eli.Stone The log in `Game_TDoR`'s `viewDidLoad`  shouldn't come up first. Can you post updated `NextBTN` method code?

Comment: Thank you very Much for your help!, just after i posted the updates i released why its not working. See the update above! Thank you again sorry for wasting your time. Eli

Comment: @Eli.Stone You are welcome! BTW you do not need screen **and** screen1, just one of the two

Answer (score 0):

Merely including the header file will not make the variable available. You are only including the definition of the class (class is for PHP what @interface is for Obj-C) You have to instantiate Game_Info and access the variable via the instance of Game_Info.

Comment: @Eli Hmm, you should brush up on some tutorials. One way to instantiate a class, you do `Game_Info *myGameInfo = [[Game_Info alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

groupName is a member (ivar) of Game_Info. Its default visibility is @protected, so any classes outside Game_Info can't access it, unless they derive from Game_Info. To make groupName accessible, you can either create a property that exposes it, or you can make it @public. How this is done is documented in the vast documentation for Xcode.

But groupName, being an ivar (instance variable) of an object, only exists if there is in fact an instance of the Game_Info. I assume you have some globally accessible instance of Game_Info in your program, let's call it globalGameInfo. Now you can access its groupName using

```
UITextField *gName = [globalGameInfo groupName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this in .h file in SecondViewController

```
NSString *strABC;
```

Make below function in SecondViewController.m

```
-(void)setString:(NSString *)strEntered{
    strABC=strEntered;
}
```

Now In First view controller do like this:

```
SecondViewController.m *objSecond = [[SecondViewController.m] initwithNibName:@"secondView.xib" bundle:nil];

[objSecond setString:@"Comment Controller"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecond animated:YES];
[objSecond release];
```

Now, In secondViewController viewWillAppear Method write this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      lblUserInput.text = strABC;
}
```

Please check spelling mistakes as I hand written this. Hope this help.

If you are not using navigationContoller then you can do something like this.

```
SecondViewControler *objSecond = [[SecondViewController] initwithNibName:@"secondview.xib" bundle:nil];
[objSecond setUserInput:txtUserInput.text];
[objSecond viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.view addSubview:objSecond];
[objSecond release];
```