# Passing variables between UIViewControllers not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to pass a variable value (in my case a simple integer) from one `UIViewController` ("MainVC") into another ("ChargeVC").

I'm having trouble getting this to work and after a day spent on so reading through the available answers, I now made an account so I'd have a change to get an answer that works for me. I found "[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716855/best-way-to-pass-variables-between-views)" pretty helpful and thought it should work, but it didn't for me.

I'm obviously new to "xcode" & "Objective-C", but I have solid "PHP" and "Javascript" knowledge.

Here is my code :

**MainVC.m**

```
NSUInteger index = 4;  //will be an index ID used for accessing a table row

ChargeVC *myChargeViewCont = [[ChargeVC alloc] init];
myChargeViewCont.title = @"Charge User";
myChargeViewCont.personIndex = index;

NSLog(@"person index MainVC: %d", [myChargeViewCont personIndex]);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:myChargeViewCont animated:YES];
```

**ChargeVC.h**

```
@interface ChargeVC : UIViewController {
    NSUInteger personIndex;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger personIndex;
@end
```

**ChargeVC.m**

```
#import "ChargeVC.h"
@implementation ChargeVC

@synthesize personIndex;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"person index ChargeVC: %d", personIndex);
}
```

As a check i tried to output the value once in "MainVC" and once in "ChargeVC". Here is the Log:

```
2014-05-11 12:17:51.242 Kunden[58238:60b] person index ChargeVC: 0
2014-05-11 12:17:51.244 Kunden[58238:60b] person index MainVC: 4
```

Am I totally missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

I found the error and posted an answer to explain. If you know what exactly happened there, I'd be eager to know.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help. I'll try to get it right by myself the next time.

Comment: Where do you make the ChargeVC controller? In a xib or storyboard? In code? Your problem might be creating an instance of that controller with alloc init.

Comment: I have neither .xib nor storyboards. I prefer to do everything in code. A lesson learned from my early FLash/Actionscript days. Could this still be a problem?

Comment: No, if you made the controller in code, then alloc init should be ok. Is the log output you show actually in that order? The log in MainVC should log first, since at the time you do that log, the view of ChargeVC shouldn't have been loaded yet.

Comment: Yes, that is the actual order. I figured it was supposed to be like this. Doesn't the alloc init create the view and also run the code in viewDidLoad?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, unless you're creating or accessing the the view in the init method. If the view is made in code, then you should be doing that in loadView.

Comment: This kind of did the trick. For now I simply replaced the `(void)viewDidLoad` with `(void)loadView` but now it enters an endless loop until the app crashes. Can you point me in the right direction? I feel you're on to something here.

Comment: I would have to see what code you have in the loadView and init methods.

Comment: You did it! I was setting view properties inside `- (id)initWithNibName`. Now that I have removed that, it loads in the correct order **and** receives the variable value! Thanks so much.

My bad for wanting to post less code. Had I posted more/all of it, you'd probably figured it out instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error and it seems I left out a crucial piece of code from my question, or you had probably immediately recognized it. Sorry about that. I'll post what I've learned.

Earlier in "ChargeVC.m" I had set

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

For reasons I don't fully understand, me setting a value for `self.view.backgroundColor` there triggered something and the `personIndex` variable always got lost and/or wasn't accessible during `viewDidLoad`. As soon as I removed the function, `personIndex` showed up.

Thanks to [rdelmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285133/rdelmar), who got me on the right track to figuring this out and to all others who helped.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to initalize it like

```
    @interface ChargeVC : UIViewController {
    NSUInteger personIndex;
    }
    @property (nonatomic) NSUInteger personIndex;
    @end
```

Just doing

```
 @interface ChargeVC : UIViewController
 @property NSUInteger personIndex; 
 @end
```

is plenty. You can access them in .m by doing `self.personIndex`. Also, don't bother with nonatomic stuff unless you understand it or is making this for production. That stuff is confusing, and if you're learning it's easier to learn that later on. (I'm assuming hobby project, apologies if this is wrong).

Otherwise, your code seems correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I assumed, this would do the trick, but sadly, it didn't. It helped me clean up the ivars on other viewcontrollers too, which **do** work the same way, but this one just won't.
For now, it is indeed a hobby/learning project, but I hope that once I read up a little more I'll be able to publish small app projects as well.

Comment: I disagree regarding nonatomic. You almost always want nonatomic, and should get in the habit of using nonatomic unless you know what atomic does and why you need it. I personally think the language designers made a mistake by making atomic the default. atomic is only needed if you are writing a class that will be accessed from multiple threads simultaneously. If not, it makse your program significantly slower for no good reason.

Comment: @DuncanC I wholeheartedly agree that it is important, but as he's learning, all those keywords are confusing. When I started out I thought so at least. My point was that he should start with the simple stuff.

Comment: Thanks again, you did help me a lot with understanding a little better what each of the parts does. I also read up on the atomic/nonatomic keywords and for the time being I guess I'll leave them out, until the app actually requires it.

I updated my post with the solution (my error) I found, so that others can avoid this mistake in the future. As soon as I have 15 reputation, I'll also mark your answers as helpful. They were very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

similar to what Oscar said, I expect there is confusion between your *personIndex* *ivar* and your *personIndex* property.

I would do this, removing the ivar declaration:

```
@interface ChargeVC : UIViewController
@property ( nonatomic ) NSUInteger personIndex ;
@end
```

Also, in your `@implementation`, `@synthesize` is assumed by default, you can leave that out too.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me drastically simplify my code, as I threw out the ivar declarations on my other viewcontrollers too, but sadly, as I said in my answer to Oscar, it did not yet fix my problem.

Comment: are you setting this var somewhere else in your code? try implementing setPersonIndex: and put a break point in it

Comment: I had tried that and it did not change anything. I have found my error though and updated my post, so that others can avoid this mistake in the future. As soon as I have 15 reputation, I'll also mark your answers as helpful. They were very much appreciated.

Comment: you can post an answer to your own question below and accept that.